# Can't load rggobi.dll though it appears to be available

Tags: r, dll

I'm trying to use `clusterfly` which depends on `rggobi`.

I load `clusterfly` and receive this error:

```
> pacman::p_load(caret, clusterfly, devtools, geonames, inTrees, mclust, party, 
+                RDSTK, reshape, ROCR, RRF, sqldf, stringi, tree, xlsx)
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/rggobi/libs/x64/rggobi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.

Failed with error:  ‘package ‘rggobi’ could not be loaded’
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/clusterfly_0.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 64469 bytes (62 KB)
downloaded 62 KB

package ‘clusterfly’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\hackr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpopFKT2\downloaded_packages

clusterfly installed
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/rggobi/libs/x64/rggobi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.

Failed with error:  ‘package ‘rggobi’ could not be loaded’
Warning message:
In pacman::p_load(caret, clusterfly, devtools, geonames, inTrees,  :
  Failed to install/load:
clusterfly
```

which seems to basically say that `rggobi.dll` is not located where it's supposed to be.

So, I try directly installing and loading `rgobbi` and get the same error:

```
> install.packages("rggobi")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/rggobi_2.1.20.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 422326 bytes (412 KB)
downloaded 412 KB

package ‘rggobi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\hackr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpopFKT2\downloaded_packages
> require(rggobi)
Loading required package: rggobi
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/rggobi/libs/x64/rggobi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.
```

I find this strange, so I have a look in Windows Explorer and the file `rggobi.dll` is right where it's supposed to be:

[image: rggobi.dll]

After another failed attempt to load it, my next thought is that there could be some sort of file permission problem. So, starting with the `rggobi` folder, I `chmod 777` to set the maximally permissions.

I still can't load the package and I repeated the process of `chmod 777` and attempting to `require(gobbi)` for each successive folder level and directly on `rggobi.dll`:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library>chmod 777 rggobi
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library>cd rggobi
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi>ls
DESCRIPTION  LICENSE  Meta       NEWS  data  help  libs
INDEX        MD5      NAMESPACE  R     demo  html
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi>chmod 777 libs
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi>cd libs
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi\libs>chmod 777 x64
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi\libs>chmod 777 i386
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi\libs>cd x64
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi\libs\x64>ls
rggobi.dll  symbols.rds
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\library\rggobi\libs\x64>chmod 777 rggobi.dll
```

Finally, after opening an issue on Github, Hadley Wickham deferred to a [lawremi](https://github.com/lawremi), who suggested trying 32-bit R, but that also led to the same result.

How can I make this dll/package available to R?

Comment: Didn't you get a pop-up window asking if to install GTK+?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't. I'm 99% I've installed it within the past month, but I can/will verify that. I have the most recent version of GIMP and I think some other R package I've used uses GTK+... verifying that now...  --> Update: I definitely have a recent version of GTK+

Comment: Hmm. it failed for me too. I wonder if you need to specify a path like for `rjava` package.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Do you mean with `lib.loc`? I tried a few variations on this: `> library(rggobi, lib.loc = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.2.0\\library", verbose = T, warn.conflicts = T)
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/rggobi/libs/x64/rggobi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rggobi’`

Comment: No, I mean [this](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32_tutorial.php)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Right, I have GTK+ but I thought you meant to specify the package location of `rgobbi` in your latter comment. So, I should specify the location of GTK+? Can you give me an example of what you mean (like where would I specify that -- in the library statement?) ; `require("RGtk2")
Loading required package: RGtk2
> require("rggobi")
Loading required package: rggobi
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/rggobi/libs/x64/rggobi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.`

Comment: What you mean? The provided link shows how to specify the path. Did you go thru it? Though I'm not sure this is the problem. This is how I solved the `rjava` issues I had.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oh I'm sorry I thought you were just showing me the GTK+ homepage, but yes, it's already in my `PATH` and I haven't had any messages related to GTK+

Comment: Maybe trigger an issue on GH

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, agreed. I'm going to do so now. Thanks for your help David.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to follow the instructions below from [here](http://www.ggobi.org/rggobi/)

> If you also want to install rggobi, you can install everything from
>   within R, with the following command:
>   `source("http://www.ggobi.org/downloads/install.r")`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

I pasted it in R

```
source("http://www.ggobi.org/downloads/install.r")
```

then it asked if I want to install GTK+ and then an **application** ggobi.
Then a restart of R is needed.

If the two applications are not found, installed in the system, R will report that it cannot load the rggobi.dll. Make sure you install not only the package but the two applications.

Comment: That's what it does when it's working properly. At the time I wrote this there was an actual bug, which has now been fixed.